# Auto select item in combo box from a entry selection in another combo box

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to VB.  I have a three column list on sheet 1 (Acct#, Name, Address).  I have a user form on a different sheet with 3 combo boxes.  Each Combo box has a list of one of the columns on sheet 1 (one has the list from Acct#, another the list from Name, the other the list from Address).  When I select an item in one of the combo boxes I would like the entry in the other two combo boxes to be auto updated with its matching entry from the 3 column list on sheet 1. The order of the first combo box selected on the user form should be random.

Is there a way to do this in VB without the use of dependent combo boxes?
Thanks, Rick

Comment: If you're any good with Excel formulae (outside of VBA) then you might know MATCH. Use the combobox change event to fire a match, then use the match row with column number to get the corresponding value.

Comment: Thank you - I will try that.